# test method is running infinitely until i forcebly stop it

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

```
@Test
void interruptedExceptionThrownByCompletableFutures() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    //given
    when(patientsClient.getPatientTreatmentDetails(RPT_TOKEN, "123", CLINICAL_ID))
            .thenReturn(createPatientTreatmentDetails());
    CompletableFuture<List<HDTreatmentOrder>> hdFuture = spy(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList()));
    when(hdFuture.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());

    CompletableFuture<List<PDTreatmentOrder>> pdFuture = spy(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList()));
    when(pdFuture.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());

    when(hdService.getData(any(), any())).thenReturn(hdFuture);
    when(pdService.getData(any(), any())).thenReturn(pdFuture);

    when(tDService.getData(RPT_TOKEN,
            "123", filter)).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new PatientTreatmentDetails()));
    //then
    assertThrows(PatientOrderException.class, () -> treatmentOrderService.getTreatmentOrders("123", filter, RPT_TOKEN));
}
```

This is treatMentOrderService
public class TreatmentOrderService {

```
private final HDTreatmentOrderService hdService;
private final PDTreatmentOrderService pdService;
private final TreatmentDetailsService tDService;
private final TreatmentOrderTransform transformer;
private final DenodoLastTreatmentDetailsService denodoLastTreatmentDetailsService;


    CompletableFuture<List<PDTreatmentOrder>> pdFuture = pdService.getData(mpi, filter);
    try {
        if (filter.isIncludeTreatmentDetails() && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(filter.getClinicId())) {
            CompletableFuture<PatientTreatmentDetails> tDFuture = tDService.getData(rptToken, mpi, filter);
            CompletableFuture.allOf(hdFuture, pdFuture, tDFuture).join();
            return transformer.transform(hdFuture.get(), pdFuture.get(), tDFuture.get(), filter);
        } else {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(hdFuture, pdFuture).join();
            return transformer.transform(hdFuture.get(), pdFuture.get(), null, filter);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new PatientOrderException("Failed executing async tasks: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        log.error("ExecutionException: ", e);
        throw new PatientOrderException("Failed executing async tasks: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

```
Nov 09, 2022 12:44:51 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator lambda$logTestDescriptorExclusionReasons$7
INFO: 0 containers and 20 tests were Method or class mismatch


PatientTreatmentDetails cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
PatientTreatmentDetails cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

    at app//com.davita.ehr.orders.patientorder.service.TreatmentOrderServiceTest.setup(TreatmentOrderServiceTest.java:84)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:76)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:506)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$21(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:491)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:51661', transport: 'socket'
TreatmentOrderServiceTest > interruptedExceptionThrownByCompletableFutures() FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue at TreatmentOrderServiceTest.java:84
```

-> This test is not executing and when i run this individually this is running continuously until i stop. i'm thinking there is some thing wrong with this test especially the completable future with spy.

using java 17
springboot 2.6.6
junit 5
gradle 7.4.2

Comment: It's unclear how all the stubbing you have done is involved in the actual method you invoke.  What is `treatmentOrderService`?  How is it initialized?  Does it contain the actual objects that you have stubbed in this method?

Comment: treatmentOrderService added

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger, to identify which line it is actually getting stuck at ?

Comment: added the debug result

Comment: You only mock `.get()`, not `.join()`, which will still wait the result is there (that is... never).

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite this part

```
CompletableFuture<List<HDTreatmentOrder>> hdFuture = spy(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList()));
when(hdFuture.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException())
```

as

```
doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(hdFuture).get();
```

The same for the other spy:

```
CompletableFuture<List<PDTreatmentOrder>> pdFuture = spy(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList()));
when(pdFuture.get()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
```

as

```
doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(pdFuture).get();
```

Comment: what is the return type of tDService.getData() function?

Comment: PatientTreatmentDetails

Comment: Then I was wrong, I'll change my answer soon.

Comment: getting this error

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I edited my answer again. Please try it like this:  doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(pdFuture).get();

Comment: the test keep on running but not executing

Comment: same issue is coming again while debugging

Comment: So answer accepted? :)

Answer (score 0):

When spying on the `CompletableFuture`s like that, they don't seem to be considered "completed" by `CompletableFuture.join()`.

I think what you should use instead is:

```
when(hdService.getData(any(), any())).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new InterruptedException()));
when(pdService.getData(any(), any())).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new InterruptedException()));
```

and you don't need the `hdFuture` and `pdFuture` spies.

Your exception handling in `TreatmentOrderService` may need fixing, but the test completes instead of hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is probably no need for the `CompletableFuture.join()`. Since you're doing the `.get()`s in the next line, the thread will block at that point until the futures complete one way or another anyway.

Simply removing the `CompletableFuture.allOf(...).join()` lines (and the modifications recommended by @pzelenovic) result in the test passing (except for unnecessary stubbings...).